# Python Prediction for organism population growth

Tags: python, loops

The inputs would be:

The initial number of organisms
The rate of growth (a real number greater than 1)
The number of hours it takes to achieve this rate
A number of hours during which the population grows

I have:

```
Population = int(input("The initial number of organisms: " ))
RateOfGrowth = int(input("The rate of growth (a real number > 0): " ))
HrToAchieve = int(input("The number of hours it takes to achieve this rate: " ))
Input_Hrs = int(input("Enter the total hours of growth: " ))

NewGrowth = 0
Passes = Input_Hrs/HrToAchieve

while Passes > 0:
    NewGrowth = (Population * RateOfGrowth)-Population
    Population += NewGrowth
    Passes -= 1

print("The total population is", Population )
```

New at loops and not sure how I'm missing a pass
partially working with input 10,2,2,6 providing correct answer of 80

But when using 100 organisms with growth rate of 5 over 2 hrs over 25 hrs total, I get 7000 NOT
24414062500 which would be proper.

Comment: You might find [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) helpful here.

Comment: How would you calculate this by hand? Draw up a flow chart/algorithm, and then implement that, or publish it so that we can help you better :)

Comment: Neither ORG nor GR change in the loop, so the growth is indeed linear, and the output of 7000 looks correct for your inputs.

Comment: example, one might start with a population of 500 organisms, a growth rate of 2, and a growth period to achieve this rate of 6 hours. Assuming that none of the organisms die, this would imply that this population would double in size every 6 hours. Thus, after allowing 6 hours for growth, we would have 1000 organisms, and after 12 hours, we would have 2000 organisms.

Comment: You are probably then missing an `ORG = Growth` statement in your loop.

Comment: @KrisA you've just described an exponential relationship, but there's no exponentiation ( `**`) in your code.

Comment: edited it a bit to make it easier to see. Simply don't get how it can work for several runs but when I do the combo 100,5,2,25 I'm pulling 122070312500 now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one line and Im assuming if the growth rate of x is there in y hours and there are less than y hours left, then there wont be any growth whatsoever.

```
import math

ORG = int(input("The initial number of organisms: " ))
GR = int(input("The rate of growth (a real number > 0): " ))
GR_Hr = int(input("The number of hours it takes to achieve this rate: " ))
PG_Hr = int(input("Enter the total hours of growth: " ))

Growth = ORG * int(math.pow(GR, PG_Hr//GR_Hr))  # or Growth = ORG * int(GR ** (PG_Hr // GR_Hr))
```

**EDIT USING LOOPS**

```
Growth_using_loops = ORG
loop_counter = PG_Hr//GR_Hr # double slash // returns a integer instead of float
for i in range(loop_counter):
    Growth_using_loops = Growth_using_loops * GR


print(Growth)
print(Growth_using_loops)
```

Output :

```
The initial number of organisms: 100
The rate of growth (a real number > 0): 5
The number of hours it takes to achieve this rate: 2
Enter the total hours of growth: 25
24414062500
24414062500
```

Comment: TY very much, but looking to learn the basics right now, more precisely loops

Comment: @KrisA Edited my answer for loops solutions as well.